# How to get the DOM object

Tags: javascript, html, events

How can I get the (innermost) DOM object that the mouse cursor points to? Unlike other events, a **keyup** event's `e.target` returns only a rough object like html body. I want to know the innermost DOM object on keyup events, just like what is returned by `e.target` of a `click` event.

Comment: [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint)

Comment: key event's only have a target in editable fields, or contentEditable elements. 

If nothing is selected or focused on, the window is the target of all the key events.

Comment: @kennebec I know that. The question is how to get around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
document.body.onmousemove = function ( e ) {
    var topmost = document.elementFromPoint( e.clientX, e.clientY );
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yVtsn/1/

Comment: Amazingly fast response with all the coding.

Comment: Actually, when I change `onmousemove` event to `keyup` event, `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` seems to become undefined, and does not work.

Comment: @sawa Yes, because `keyup` is not a mouse event. I'm not sure that it's possible to access the mouse coordinates from outside of a mouse event.

Comment: I was able to get around this by using `onmouseover` with your code to keep track of the object, and using that for the code for `keyup`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to jQuery...

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MPTTp/)

There's a really cool function called `document.elementFromPoint` which does what it sounds like.

What we need is to find the x and y coords of the mouse and then call it using those values:

```
var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
    elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

[**document.elementFromPoint**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)

[**jQuery event object**](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this - and if you don't know how to do it without jQuery, you're bad. http://jsfiddle.net/kpLJR/

Comment: @jsfiddle.net/kpLJR if you use jquery why would you not use the jquery function, therefor future proofing your self to some extent from the changes made to browsers?! And why are you bad if you dont know how to do it without jquery?